# Draw circle on top of image in Flutter programatically

Tags: flutter, dart, canvas, bitmap

I have an image that I obtain using `RepainBoundary`

```
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        RecordableWidget.previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    double pxRatio = 0.5;
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pxRatio);
```

And I want to draw a circle on top of this image before saving it to disk.

I Android, I did something like this:

```
val canvas = Canvas(image)
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint)
saveImage(image)
```

I can't figure out how to do the same in Flutter

Comment: how about CustomPainter  https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html

Comment: I am not trying to render it on the screen, I just want to render  it in memoy then save the file